# How to change term reference field according to role?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have the following challenge: I have 4 roles, let's call them **Group1** ... **Group4**. I have different content types and I segregate access of those types using the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module. So users from Group1 can only view and edit nodes that have term Group1.

Now, I have the challenge to change a term reference field of these content types automatically. So if a user from role **Group1** creates a new node, that node will have a term reference field with term **Group1**.

I don't want users to edit on their own to avoid human errors.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Rules? Custom coding? And are you sure you need a field? If it's always same term for given author, why not to process this at display stage, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create separate fields for respective roles. Use [Field permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions). Or if you want to have role wise access like from editor -> moderator -> pulisher etc. Use [workfolw](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow) module.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create 4 similar rules (1 for each group), which would look like so (for Group1):

- Event: before saving content
- Condition: user has role Group1
- Action:

  1. Set a data value.
  2. Select the taxonomy term reference field to set.
  3. Select the taxonomy term 'Group1' (if needed: use the "Switch to the direct input mode" button to reveal the terms available in your taxonomy).

Repeat the above steps for Group2, 3 and 4 to create a similar rule.

You might want to try to consolidate those 4 (similar) rules in a single rule, by using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module: the condition for each group would be replace by a similar "if condition" (contained in the rules action), and the Rules action for each group would only be executed if the "if condition" would be true. For a sample using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module (for which there is not a lot of docu available), refer to my answer to the question "[How to prevent a node being saved when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-prevent-a-node-being-saved-when-using-the-rules-module/178623#178623)".