# How to send an email to a specific user on new account creation using Rules?

Tags: users, rules, emails

I have an alumni association portal. When a new user creates profile on the portal, that account stays blocked until a specific user from that batch/department approves it.

I am trying to make use of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but not able to.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please elaborate your question with more details and describe what approaches you tried implementing with what results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do setting "admin/config/people/accounts" to sent notification email on account activation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Rule which you can import in your own environment (provided you have the Rules UI enabled, a sub-module of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)):

```
{"rules_send_mail_about_new_account" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send mail about new account",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "user_insert" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "someone@example.com",
          "subject" : "New account created",
          "message" : "A new account got created ..."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adapt the eMail content to fit your needs, eg replace the `someone@example.com` by the appropriate eMail id. You may also want to use any of the available tokens to include it in the subject of message of the eMail.

To refine the above rule, so that you can have a specific user for each department (as in your question), you can use the "[Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. Provided you have some user profile field that indicates which department this user relates to (and which you can check via a Rules Condition). If you then create 1 such (similar) rule you'd done, though you might end up with a lot of rules (1 for each department). Soo you may want to group them together using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module.

For an example using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module (for which there is not a lot of docu available), refer to my answer to the question "[How to prevent a node being saved when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114955/how-to-prevent-a-node-being-saved-when-using-the-rules-module/178623#178623)".

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/config/people/accounts

Under **Registration and cancellation** section see **Who can register accounts?**

Click on the **Visitors, but administrator approval is required**  and save